# How Do i Add a " into php string function

Tags: php, string

okay so i use this function below to create a string i need using text and variables within the php script

```
$result_string = "/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js " . $proxy .  " " . $button . " 2>&1";
```

This is the output i see

```
/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js 192.192.192.0 81.88.88.88 2>&1
```

But the Problem is I need to Add " in the output --  i need the output to look like this

```
/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js "192.192.192.0" "81.88.88.88" 2>&1
```

I have tried so many ways to add "" around the two variables without affecting the function but still not able to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result_string = "/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js \"" . $proxy .  "\" \"" . $button . "\" 2>&1";
```

or

```
$result_string = '/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js "' . $proxy .  '" "' . $button . '" 2>&1';
```

Comment: the first one shows /usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js "proxy" "button" 2>&1

Answer (score 3):

There are two options.  Either use single quotes, or escape the double quotes:

Single quote:

```
$result_string = '/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js "' . $proxy . "' '" . $button . ' 2>&1';
```

Escaping double quotes:

```
$result_string = "/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js \"" . $proxy .  "\" \"" . $button . "\" 2>&1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the " with \

```
\"
```

or you can wrap your string with '

```
'/usr/local/bin/casperjs test.js "...'
```

Also, you should read and learn the basics in PHP :P